# How to access Azure SQL Database via MSI in PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

is it possible to connect to Azure SQL Database by using Managed Service Identity? I'd like to rip out SQL credentials.

Thank you for your advises!

Best

Comment: From what? That's what makes the difference. From C# or powershell code? Most likely. From SSIS or SSAS? No

Comment: From PowerShell

Comment: And is the powershell executed in Azure automation?

Comment: To save back and forth please post MVC https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. See this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/msi-tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Managed Service Identity in Azure function you can have a look at this article:

[How to use Azure Managed Service Identity (public preview) in App Service and Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity)

To authenticate to SQL with a Managed Service Identity you can have look at this article:

[Azure SQL authentication with a Managed Service Identity](https://winterdom.com/2017/10/19/azure-sql-auth-with-msi)

It should be enough to achieve what you need.